# Python copy paster files

Tags: python, copy-paste, shutil

I am trying to copy and paste an specific files, using an ID  as key to find each file. However, I encountered this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S:/Risk/Folder/DailyLetters//210996712201.pdf'
```

I put a for loop to go ID by ID to find all the files and copy into the new path.

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil

NewFilePath=r'C:\Users\GWEBB\Desktop\\'
NewFile='cases.xlsx' #AQUI CAMBIO
NewFilePath =NewFilePath.replace('\\', '/')
     
File= pd.read_excel(f'{NewFilePath}{NewFile}', sheet_name="Sheet1")

File=File[['ID']]

File['ID']= File['ID'].astype(str)

for i, row in File.iterrows():
    case_number=File['ID'].loc[i]
    original = r'S:\Risk\Folder\DailyLetters\\{0}.pdf'.format(case_number)
    original =original.replace('\\', '/')
    target = r'C:\Users\GWEBB\Desktop\Cases\{0}.pdf'.format(case_number)
    target =target.replace('\\', '/')
    shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is pretty straightforward... the path is invalid / the file doesn't exist. If you're positive that the file is there, then double check that the path leading up to that file is correct. I suspect the 2 slashes in the middle of the path to be the culprit ("S:/Risk/Folder/DailyLetters **//** 210996712201.pdf"). Also, your drive usually should have 2 slashes after it ("S://").

Comment: Hi, the file exists, and 2 slashes didn't work [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S://Risk/CFO_Risk/CNP/Special Collections/Completed - Daily Tracker/DailyLetters//210996712201.pdf'

Comment: What about removing the double slashes at the end, just before the file name? ("DailyLetters _//_ 210996712201.pdf")

Comment: @Xiddoc if I try this works, how I can for loop my dataframe and copy and paster every file by his id
for i, row in File.iterrows():
    case='519097813'
    original = r'S:\Risk\Folder\DailyLetters\{0}.pdf'.format(case)
    target = r'C:\Users\GWEBB\Desktop\Cases\{0}.pdf'.format(case)
    shutil.copyfile(original, target)

Comment: That is a different question, make a new thread for it.